# Admob Rewarded ads without button

Tags: android, admob

So my problem is actually pretty simple. I have a Rewardable admob adview, but it is triggered right now in a onclick method. How can I first some how load the Rewardvideoad and then display it without an onclick method ?

my oncreate method:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_admob);


        weekname = getIntent().getExtras().getString("week");
        score = getIntent().getExtras().getString("score");
        username = getIntent().getExtras().getString("username");

        button4 = findViewById(R.id.button4);
        button4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (mRewardedVideoAd.isLoaded()) {
                    mRewardedVideoAd.show();
                }
            }
        });

        MobileAds.initialize(this, "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~3347511713");
        mRewardedVideoAd = MobileAds.getRewardedVideoAdInstance(this);
        mRewardedVideoAd.setRewardedVideoAdListener(this);

        loadRewardedVideoAd();

    }
private void loadRewardedVideoAd() {
    mRewardedVideoAd.loadAd("ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/5224354917",
            new AdRequest.Builder().build());
}
```

Please help,

Thanks;)

Answer (score 0):

This is not allowed to show the [rewarded ad without opt-in](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/rewarded-ads#show_the_ad).

> Before displaying a rewarded ad to users, you must present the user
>   with an explicit choice to view rewarded ad content in exchange for a
>   reward. Rewarded ads must always be an opt-in experience.